# MySQL - Trying to return a single row for each distinct DATE; showing CASH, CREDIT, and grand TOTAL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to consolidate each unique DATE into a single row.  What I'm getting instead is total for CASH being returned as 1 row, then total for CREDIT being returned as another row.  How do I consolidate these rows into a single row grouped by DATE?

See my query below:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT orders.service_date,

/* CASH TOTAL */
CASE WHEN
customer.payment_type = "Cash"
THEN

CONCAT('$',
(SELECT   

SUM(
    ((CASE
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MT'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MTF'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtfrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MTB'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtbrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
  END) + cast(((orders.cu + orders.pw + orders.r + orders.lr + orders.misc) * 0.80) as DECIMAL(10,2)))))) 

  ELSE 
  " - "   
  END as Cash,


  /* CREDIT TOTAL */
  CASE WHEN
customer.payment_type = "Credit"
THEN

CONCAT('$',
(SELECT   

SUM(
    ((CASE
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MT'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MTF'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtfrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MTB'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtbrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
  END) + cast(((orders.cu + orders.pw + orders.r + orders.lr + orders.misc) * 0.80) as DECIMAL(10,2)))))) 

  ELSE 
  " - "   
  END as Credit,

  /* GRAND TOTAL */

  CONCAT('$',
(SELECT   

SUM(
    ((CASE
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MT'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MTF'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtfrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
    WHEN
      orders.service= 'MTB'
        THEN
          cast(customer.mtbrate as DECIMAL(10,2))
  END) + cast(((orders.cu + orders.pw + orders.r + orders.lr + orders.misc) * 0.80) as DECIMAL(10,2)))))) as Total

FROM finalproject.orders

INNER JOIN finalproject.customer
USING(customerid)

GROUP BY customer.payment_type, orders.service_date
ORDER BY orders.service_date ASC
```

What is being returned is this:

[image]

Most of the query you can ignore -- the arithmetic & such... I am new to MySQL ... any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: On a sidenote: Why all these casts? Aren't the values stored as decimals? As to the dollar signs: I wouldn't select these, but leave it with the GUI layer to display them or not. As to `DISTINCT`: this has no effect, as no two rows will be the same (they all differ either in service_date, cash or credit amount).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the database was auto-generated from STS ... I suppose I could run an alter statement to change them to decimals?  Also, noted about the dollar signs & the `DISTINCT`.  Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Group by `service_date` only, as you want one result row per `service_date`. Then include `payment_type` in the conditional aggration, i.e. inside `SUM`.

```
SELECT
  o.service_date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.payment_type = 'Cash' THEN
        CASE o.service
          WHEN 'MT'  THEN CAST(c.mtrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
          WHEN 'MTF' THEN CAST(c.mtfrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
          WHEN 'MTB' THEN CAST(c.mtbrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        END + 
        CAST(((o.cu + o.pw + o.r + o.lr + o.misc) * 0.80) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
      END
  ) AS cash,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.payment_type = 'Credit' THEN
        CASE o.service
          WHEN 'MT'  THEN CAST(c.mtrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
          WHEN 'MTF' THEN CAST(c.mtfrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
          WHEN 'MTB' THEN CAST(c.mtbrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        END + 
        CAST(((o.cu + o.pw + o.r + o.lr + o.misc) * 0.80) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
      END
  ) AS credit,
  SUM(CASE o.service
        WHEN 'MT'  THEN CAST(c.mtrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        WHEN 'MTF' THEN CAST(c.mtfrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        WHEN 'MTB' THEN CAST(c.mtbrate AS DECIMAL(10,2))
      END + 
      CAST(((o.cu + o.pw + o.r + o.lr + o.misc) * 0.80) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
  ) AS total
FROM finalproject.orders o
JOIN finalproject.customer c USING (customerid)
GROUP BY o.service_date
ORDER BY o.service_date;
```

Comment: You cleaned that right up! I need to learn more about SQL syntax like "o.orders" & these abbreviations.  Yours looks super clean & worked like charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

by using group by `customer.payment_type, orders.service_date`, you are going  to create 2 lines for the same day

Comment: When I did only `GROUP BY orders.service_date` it was returning a syntax error ... how should I phrase it?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest (maybe little dirty solution) - wrap it in another SELECT:

`SELECT service_date, cash, credit, sum(total) as total from (-your original query-) as o group by o.service_date`

Comment: Still getting this error... trying to interpret it.  I sort of see what you were saying though.

`Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'o.Cash' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Yes, this is dirty and I don't recommend this approach. The error stems from `cash, credit` by the way. You would have to aggregate the columns, e.g. `max(cash), max(credit)`. At last you should add an `order by` clause.